# Elements moving around for some unknown reason

Tags: html, css

Whenever I change the id of the first subheading from `aulas_subheading_2` to `aulas_subheading_1`. Some strange things happen to my layout, the `aulas_heading_1` heading seems to disappear!

It goes from this:
[image: Before]

To this:
[image: After]

I inspected the elements with firebug and identified that they are behind the divider, the aulas_heading1_band, which is in position:relative

What's going on here?

The relevant markup:

HTML

```
 <section id="aulas_container">
  <div id="aulas_container_top">
    <h1 id="aulas_heading_1"><span class="highlight1">Aulas de Inglês</span></h1> 
    <h2 id="aulas_subheading_2">Práticas Imersivas</h2>
    <div id="aulas_heading_band_1"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="aulas_container_bottom">
    <h1 id="aulas_heading_1">Aulas</h1>
    <h2 id="aulas_subheading_2"><span class="highlight2">com Professores Nativos</span></h2>
    <div id="aulas_subheading_band">a</div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#aulas_container {
  background-position: center top;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 910px;
}

#aulas_container_top {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/6Tv6r7F.png");
}

#aulas_container_bottom {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/YfxsPWu.jpg");
}

/*                       */
/*         TEXT          */
/*                       */
#aulas_heading_1 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

#aulas_subheading_1 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: white;
}

#aulas_heading_2 {
  color: black;
}

#aulas_subheading_2 {
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: black;
}

/*                       */
/*  DIVIDERS AND SHAPES  */
/*                       */
#aulas_heading_band_1 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 35%;
  position: relative;
  top: -40%;
  background-color: black;
}

*#aulas_heading_band_1:before {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: -30%;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

#aulas_subheading_band {
  background-color: white;
  height: 10%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0%;
}


#aulas_subheading_2_band{
  background-color: $binaryColor0;
  height: 5%;
  }
```

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, only post the compiled CSS.

Comment: sorry. i changed it.

Comment: Looking over your CSS and HTML IDs, the markup has the prefix `aulas_` and the CSS has the prefix `aprende_`.

Comment: Whoops! My mistake. I grabbed the wrong piece of CSS. I'll fix it as soon ASAP.